# How do I make a scrollTo +numberofpixels instead of anchor-dependent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrollto

I am trying to create a next/prev scrollTo on a horizontal navigation (slideshow-like), and can't find any articles on how to scrollTo where there's no anchor involved.

How do I make it so that every time you hit Next - the scrollTo moves a certain amount of pixels instead of to an anchor?

Comment: You could use native DOM `window.scrollBy(x, y)` method.

Comment: so onclick="(#container).scrollBy(400, 0)" ? I am asking because I am not confident in js syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use [scrollLeft()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) for that:

```
$('#next').on('click', function() {
    var scroll = $('body').scrollLeft();
    $('body').animate({ scrollLeft : scroll + 400 });
});
```